# Why React uses antd's < Pagination />; The component onChange property can be directly bound to setCurrent?

Tags: react-hooks, antd

First I used React Hooks: useState

```js
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(1)
```

Then I want to implement a pager effect using the Pagination component from Antd

```js
< Pagination
simple
pageSize={pageSize}
defaultCurrent={current}
total={posts.length}
onChange={setCurrent}
/>
```

Now my question is why 'onChange ={setChange}' can do the current state update directly?

This is the code I watched a Youtuber write and I tried it myself, wondering why it works

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't work? What would you have written instead?

Comment: I want to bind a processing function, in the function to do 'setCurrent(page)' such as the setting, 'onChange' inside the 'page' parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `onChange` function of a primitive component, such as the standard `input`, the event handler is called with the event object, and you need to extract the value using the event object's properties.

When you create a component that accepts an `onChange` function you can decide what you wish to call the event handler with.

For example, AndD Pagination component is a wrapper around the Pagination component of [**rc-pagination**](https://github.com/react-component/pagination) as you can see [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/pagination/Pagination.tsx#L124). The `onChange` handler prop of **rc-pagination** has this [signature](https://github.com/react-component/pagination/blob/master/src/Pagination.tsx#L59):

```
onChange?: (page: number, pageSize: number) => void;
```

and it's called by the internal change handler (`handleChange`) [here](https://github.com/react-component/pagination/blob/master/src/Pagination.tsx#L354) with the new page, and the page size:

```
onChange(newPage, pageSize);
```

The internal `handleChange` is usually called by `onClick` handlers, and passed the new page's number.

However, since `onChange(newPage, pageSize)` accepts 2 paramters (page and number of items in page), passing `setCurrent` directly prevents you from reacting to `pageSize` changes. If you want `pageSize` as well, you'll need to updated the state and the handler function, for example:

```
const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ current: 1, pageSize: 10 })

<Pagination
  onChange={(current, pageSize) => setCurrent({ current, pageSize })}
```

Comment: Dude, I think that's a good idea, but 'onChange={setCurrent}' is the same as' onChange={page => setCurrent(page)}`,

How does that work?

Comment: Read my answer again, and look at linked code.

Comment: It was the source code that called the onChange bound function and passed it two arguments

Comment: Exactly. The parameters passed to `onChange` are implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

here you have set the `setCurrent` function as the value of `onChange` prop of the `<Pagination/>`. This `setCurrent` function is responsible for the updating of the state variable `current`. When user interacts with pagination, it will update the `current` state value. What you have to know is that `setCurrent` is a function which returned by the `useState` hook. Refer the link below for further information.

[https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-usestate-react/#:~:text=useState%20is%20React%20Hook%20that,the%20setter%20function%20is%20called](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-usestate-react/#:%7E:text=useState%20is%20React%20Hook%20that,the%20setter%20function%20is%20called).

Comment: I know it's a state update hook, but my own approach is to bind an event handler. Does setCurrent automatically bind parameters to update the current state?